# ELK real time data feeding

Tags: logging, logstash, real-time, elk

I have `linux1` vm which is used to execute batch of bash scripts.

I need to feed output logs from those scripts in real time to ELK stack which runs on another `linux2` vm.

Is that possible? Where should I start from?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course you can do that.

So if I understand you right, you want to index the logs that get produced by the scripts into your Elastic Stack.

Assuming you have log **files**, you would install [filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-getting-started.html) on linux1 and set up a [log input](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-input-log.html) to watch these certain log files. In your filebeat configuration file ([filebeat.yml](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-reference-yml.html)) you then need to define the credentials of your elasticsearch instance running on linux2.

Notice that you might have to deal with security/authentication etc. and have to configure your filebeat for that.

Comment: @norsk have you had any success with my proposal?